# «Первым долгом»: этимология

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Является ли выражение «первым долгом» (=сначала) исконным или было калькировано?

Comment: Может быть всё таки "первым делом"? (например, самолёты). "Первым долгом" я никогда не слышал.

Comment: @ddbug нет, именно "первым долгом" :) Это довольно употребляемый в прошлом фразеологизм: http://phraseologiya.academic.ru/788/первым_долгом.

Comment: Само понятие "кальки выражений" оно какое-то кривое, и на самом деле - к лингвистике не относящееся :> к риторике, истории, психологии скорее... 
То есть речь-то идет о силлогизме или метафоре или аналогии или о чем-то подобном - просто обычном выражении вроде сего, красном или не красном, а просто кому-то понравившемся  - которые просто передаются от людей к людям, а какой у них язык - это не имеет значения... :)) 
И понятие "исходные выражения" что такое, особенно в свете сего :>>

Comment: ddbug, https://goo.su/BL4

Comment: к чистой лингвистике

Answer (score 0):

Не то чтобы «сначала», а *вначале*, как когда-то «вначале было слово», оно же — обязательство, решение. Возвращать долги начинают с того времени, как себя осознают, и вряд ли кто вспомнит какой он был, этот первый долг. Правильнее говорить о всяком моменте, когда возникает естественная пауза, позволяющая осмотреться, чтобы представить дальнейшее собственное действие как логичное продолжение предыдущего.

Насчёт калькирования: если и калька, то с «исконного» фразеологизма *первым делом* и ему подобных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]